# Solving quasi linear partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to attempt to solve $$u_t +2ut u_x = tu$$, with the initial condition, $$ u(x,0)=x$$.
I have been trying the method of charecterisitcs and stuck after this step

$$ \frac{dt}{1}= \frac{dx}{2ut}= \frac{du}{tu}$$

I solved for integrals, and got $$ x= \frac{t^2}{2}$$ and $$x=2u$$. This doesn’t make sense to me. Kindly help.

Comment: The integral curves are $$x + \color{red}{C_{2}} = 2u, \quad t dt = \frac{dx}{x + C_{2}} \implies \frac{t^{2}}{2} + \color{blue}{C_{1}} = \ln (x + C_{2}) \implies \color{blue}{C_{1}} = \ln (2u) - \frac{t^{2}}{2}$$ and hence $$2u = x + f\left(\ln (2u) - \frac{t^{2}}{2} \right)$$